# GCM egistration_ids field deprecation?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Can someone clarify the status of the registration_ids field?  From my interpretation it is at risk of becoming unsupported.  What is meant by "for general purposes"?

"Though for general purposes it is deprecated, you can use registration_ids as a target for multicast messages to more than one device (up to 1000)."[1]

[1] https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, if you are using the `registration_ids` field to send messages to one device at a time, you should use the `to` field instead. Only if you are using `registration_ids` to send a message to multiple devices you should keep using it.

It's not marked as deprecated in Table 1 [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#table1), while another parameter (`notification_key`) is marked as deprecated.

That said, there's a long way from deprecated to not supported. The old C2DM service that was deprecated and replaced by GCM about 3 years ago is still supported.